# aws amplify web app returns 404 with simple website

Tags: html, aws-amplify

I have hooked up a simple html into aws amplify and built it. When I click on the production link, it just hits me with a 404 "No webpage was found for the web address". I am not sure what is going on here, the repo only has 1 html that is bare bones. Do I need more than just a html in my repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the main html file has to be called "index.html", if it is called any other name it won't find it and you will get a 404.

Comment: Its valid answer. after adding index.html able to access the app. I wonder why aws didn't put warning there. I had to spend an hour to figure it out